Can we find an exact formula for the number of square-free integers between $1$ and $n$ without summation or product?
The problem of counting the number of square-free integers between $1$ and $n$ is well studied in number theory. The exact solution is traditionally given by a formula involving the Möbius function $\mu$ and summation:
$$
Q(n) = \sum_{d \leq n} \mu(d) \left\lfloor \frac{n}{d^2} \right\rfloor,
$$
where $\mu(d)$ is the Möbius function.
This formula works perfectly to count square-free numbers, but it involves a summation over all possible integers $d$ such that $ d \leq n $. Similarly, approximations such as those derived from the product formula involving primes (e.g., Euler product over $ p $) are also well known but not exact.

This is a lovely expository paragraph. Do you have a question?

I want to find an exact formula for the number of square-free integers between $1$
and $n$ without summation or product

OEIS entry A013928 gives the "Number of (positive) squarefree numbers < n". Why do you think such an exact formula exists?

I just want to know if someone can find a formula , formulas are pretty nice than OEIS !

@Irafdpcr OEIS has a section on known formulas, and links to relevant papers. That's the place to start.

@Irafdpcr it might be better to clarify what you want the formula to be, rather than saying what you want it not to be. Asking vaguely for "a formula" is so open ended that it's basically meaningless. However, if you ask for something more specific like "a polynomial", or "an elementary function", or maybe "a formula built using only the basic operations $+,-,\times,\div,\uparrow$", then any of those questions could likely be answered (in the negative). If you want a fast algorithm, you should ask for a fast algorithm; "a formula" is often very slow when implemented literally.

An example, where $#S$ denotes the cardinality of a set $S$.
$$Q(n) = #{k\in\mathbb{N} : 1\leq k\leq n \land \forall(j\in\mathbb{N}), k/j^2\notin \mathbb{Z}}$$
This is clearly "a formula", it represents $Q$ exactly, and I never invoke product or summation, but I doubt this is what you wanted.

Your formula is just a set definition not a functional formula , let me give you an example : Problem $1$ ($2008$ Bulgarian Autumn contest, p$11.4$) Given a natural number n, find the number off all square-free positive integers a for which $\displaystyle \left\lfloor \frac{n}{\sqrt{a}}\right\rfloor$ is odd.
(Aleksandar Ivanov)
The formula for this was $n^{2}-2\cdot\operatorname{floor}\left(\frac{n^{2}}{4}\right)$
Similarly i want a formula for the number of square-free integers between $1$
and $n$
without summation or product?

@Irafdpcr To my eyes, what I wrote is a functional formula. That you're rejecting it is exactly my point. Asking for "a formula" is too vague. I gave you a formula, and it meets all your stated criteria, but you still don't like it. I could list out a thousand different formulae in a thousand different formal languages, but realistically you'll reject the vast majority of them. Don't tell us what we can't use, tell us what we can use. What is "a functional formula" to you? If you just want it to use basic arithmetic $(+,-,\times,\div,\uparrow)$ and the floor function, then just say that.

There is such a formula, using only the three basic arithmetic operations on the natural numbers $+,\times,\uparrow$, along with absolute difference $|n-k|$ and floor division $\lfloor n/k\rfloor$. More generally, every Elementary Recursive function can be given such a representation without ever using $\sum$ or $\prod$ notation. This fact was proven in the paper "Superpositions of Elementary Arithmetic functions" (Marchenkov, 2007). Essentially, Marchenkov's results show that $\sum$ and $\prod$ notation is not actually necessary to represent any such function.
You could find what that formula is by following Marchenkov's strategies, but it'll be very massive and complicated, so I don't know what it is exactly. If a simpler formula were known, it would likely be present on every article about the subject. In any case, it's not too hard to prove that $Q$ is Elementary Recursive.
$$\operatorname{sg}(n) = \frac{(n+1)-|n-1|}{2}=\begin{cases}0 &: n=0 \\ 1&:n\geq 1\end{cases}$$
$$Q(n) = \sum_{d=1}^n \operatorname{sg}\left(\prod_{j=2}^d \left(d-j^2\left\lfloor\frac{d}{j^2}\right\rfloor\right)\right)$$
By Marchenkov's results, it follows that $Q$ can be represented using only the simple elementary arithmetic operations, without needing any $\sum$ summation or $\prod$ product at all. More generally, on this question I posted recently, it's proven that any computable function which can be computed in the $\sf{ELEMENTARY}$-time hierarchy is in fact Elementary Recursive. This includes any integer function you'd find in an ordinary highschool textbook (unless the book includes tetration, I guess). By combining the results, it follows that every such function will have "a formula" using only the five elementary arithmetic operations, without needing any summation or products.
